# Proof that a function $g$ approaches its least upper bound

Tags: real-analysis

I'm struggling to show the following.

Let $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function. Suppose that there exist a constant $C\in \mathbb{R}$, such that

$$g(x)\leq C \hspace{20pt} \text{for all } x\geq 0$$

Let

$$L=\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)} g(x)$$

Show that

$$g(x)\rightarrow L \hspace{20pt} \text{for }x\rightarrow \infty$$

Does anyone have a hint as to where I should start?

Comment: Hint: For any $x_0$, it holds that $g(x_0)\leq g(x)\leq L$ for all $x\geq x_0$.

Comment: Ah, the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is just what I needed!